# How to change Back ground colour for Tkinter module?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hello I am very new with the python module Tkinter, I have written the code for a simple text editor. But I am not able to figure out how to change the background colour.
Help would be welcome thx.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

# from tkinter import filedialog
# from tkinter import font


root = Tk()
root.title('Flax')
root.iconbitmap('E:\editor.ico')
root.geometry('1200x660')

# Main Frame
my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

# ScrollBar
scroll = Scrollbar(my_frame)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# Text Box
text = Text(my_frame, width=98, height=25, font=("Helvetica", 13), selectbackground="grey", selectforeground="white", undo=True)         
        
text.pack()

scroll.config(command=text.yview)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter you need to use is `bg = "blue"` for example [source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm).

Implemented into your code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

# from tkinter import filedialog
# from tkinter import font


root = Tk()
root.title('Flax')
root.iconbitmap('E:\editor.ico')
root.geometry('1200x660')

# Main Frame
my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

# ScrollBar
scroll = Scrollbar(my_frame)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# Text Box
text = Text(my_frame, width=98, height=25, font=("Helvetica", 13), bg="grey", fg="white", undo=True)         
        
text.pack()

scroll.config(command=text.yview)

root.mainloop()
```